# Integral with sin

Tags: integration

Can you help me with solving this integral?
$$\int \frac{1}{\sin^2x}d(\sin x)$$.

Which formula should I use, $\int x^ndx$ or 
$\displaystyle \int \dfrac{1}{x}dx$ for logarithm, and why?

Comment: I find it interesting that your question is is titled "integral with sin" instead of "integral with sine."

Comment: Haha, it's because of writing many mechanically "sin" symbols.

Answer (score 3):

Put $\sin x=t$ and $d(\sin x)=dt$

So $$I =\int\frac{1}{t^2}dt=\int t^{-2}dt=-\frac{1}{t}+C$$

Answer (score 1):

Observe that $d(\sin x)=\cos x\,dx$ so your integral is equivalent to

$$I=\int \frac{\cos x}{\sin^2x}\,dx$$

from which is is clear that the substitution $u=\sin x$ and $du =\cos x\,dx$ forms

$$I=\int \frac{1}{u^2}\,du=-\frac{1}{u}+C$$